# continue to next loop if there are specific characters found in the array

Tags: arrays, vb6

I have this nested loop. I have an array called `HPArray(m)` which has a n number of characters in a string.

How do I look for 000 and 111 and 222 and 333 (yes only these 4 triplets, and they must be contiguous) and if any of these exist within the string, the for loop goes to the next m value?

```
For j = 2 To lenHP - 1
    For k = j + 1 To lenHP            
       For m = 1 To cntHP
           'need a condition here that looks for 000 or 333 or 222 or 111
            For mM = 1 To cntLP                
                'most of the processing mess happens here :)       
            Next mM          
        Next m
    Next k
Next j
```

Comment: you dont need 3 loops, just 3 Ifs using Instr for each search target

Comment: well, i tried that but it wouldnt allow me to jump to the next m value . and from what i know, the Instr is used to give the position. i dont need the position but merely ignore any string that has these characters

Comment: ...and if the search string does not exist, Instr returns -1.

Comment: ... instr() returns 0 when the string is not found .. but i agree: you should use instr()

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, all that i was missing was a label . that was a new concept to me . thanks again. it works beautifully .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If (InStr(HPArray(m), "000") > 0) Or (InStr(HPArray(m), "111") > 0) Or (InStr(HPArray(m), "222") > 0) Or (InStr(HPArray(m), "333") > 0) Then

    'Do something

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want have a stand-alone function, then the following could be used:

```
Public Function ContainsTriple(ByRef in_sValue As String) As Boolean

    Dim lAsciiDigit             As Long

    ' Digit
    For lAsciiDigit = 48 To 51 ' "0" to "3"
        If InStr(1, in_sValue, String$(3, lAsciiDigit)) > 0 Then
            ContainsTriple = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next lAsciiDigit

End Function
```

Maybe I am just using it to show an actual use for the String$() function! If you wanted to add other triples later on, you just need to adjust the For loop.